# VPS 2GB RAM memory and Symfony 3 - Out of memory

Tags: nginx, out-of-memory

I'm trying to install a symfony 3.4 project on a Debian 8 server. I'm using Nginx as web server.

My config server :

- RAM = 2 GB
- Memory  20 GB

The composer install works fine (the composer update too).
I had also an angular front in the same server. Everything had works fine (npm install, ng build, ..).

But when I request any route of my API, I get an error with code 500. I can't even get the profiler.

Inside the log file of nginx, I can see this error message [log message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D22AP.png) but I configured the php memory_limit = -1.

My nginx conf file :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server_name;
    root location/of/my/front;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}


server {
    server_name my_server_name_api;
    root location/of/my/api/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
       internal;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
     return 404;
   }

   error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

Do you have any idea ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error could be due to your PHP.ini settings file having a low limit of memory, PHP can have a set limit of memory that it's allowed to use, and typically it's not set dynamically meaning that it requires you to change it to the value that you want to use.

To do this, find the php.ini file, and find the line with `memory_limit` on it and then change it to:

```
memory_limit = -1
```

This will allow PHP to use as much ram as it can, this is not ideal in some situations, and often times you'll find most websites only need around 1gb of memory to run, so try:

```
memory_limit = 1024
```

Instead, you could look at other methods such as disabling profiler in Symfony if you are not intending on using it as it's the most eager component within Symfony. To do this add this snippet to your code and it will where you would like to disable profiler:

```
if ($this->container->has('profiler')){
    $this->container->get('profiler')->disable();
}
```

or if you want to disable to globally you can set the global parameter within the config.

```
framework:
    profiler:
        collect: false
```

You can also set the `memory_limit` vairable via PHP by putting `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` into your main .php file.

Comment: My memory_limit is already set to -1 (I checked with phpinfo()). In prod, the profiler is already disabled, isn't it ?

Comment: @L.Garin Sounds like you might need to take a look at your code and think about performance leaks such SQL & loops which are the major drains.

Comment: Actually, I have only one route and it's only a twig view (without any variable). And in local (on Ubuntu 18) everything is fine.. So I don't have any database and any loop.. That's weird